# ¿Cómo hacer setValue en un rango concreto?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Me gustaría que la información del `setValue` quede de esta manera, pero no se como hacerlo:

[image]

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
var accesoRegistro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes");
  var calculoF = accesoRegistro.getDataRange();
  var ultimaF = calculoF.getLastRow();
  z = 2;
  while (z <= ultimaF) {
    z++;
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes").getRange('A' + z).setValue(now);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes").getRange('C' + z).setValue(nombreCliente);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes").getRange('H' + z).setValue(mensajeConcepto + [suma]);
```

Esta mal, porque a la siguiente vez que ejecute el programa, se repetirán en vez de actualizarse los datos,

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. No está del todo clara tu pregunta. Por un lado el código está incompleto ya que no se incluyen las declaraciones de variables como now, nobreCliente y por otro la descripción de lo se espera que haga el script también está incompleta. Por favor agrega un [mcve].

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como hacer el setValue para que los valores se reflejen en la hoja de calculo sin repetirse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/490080/como-hacer-el-setvalue-para-que-los-valores-se-reflejen-en-la-hoja-de-calculo-si)