# Como hacer el setValue para que los valores se reflejen en la hoja de calculo sin repetirse

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Me gustaría que al ejecutar la función, la hoja de cálculo añadiera los valores de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que he realizado, pone los valores como lo deseo, pero si vuelvo a ejecutar el script, en vez de actualizarse los valores establecidos, vuelve a ponerlos debajo de los de antes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
function comprobarFacturaPorHoras(nombreCliente, filaCliente, fechaRango) {
 var now = new Date();
  now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");

var date = new Date();
  var mt = date.getMonth();
  var months = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"];
  var currentD = months[mt];
  var mensajeConcepto = "Desarrollo horas " + currentD + ': ';

var calculoF = accesoRegistro.getDataRange();
  var ultimaF = calculoF.getLastRow();
  z = 2;
//Supongo que el fallo tiene que estar por aquí
  var accesoRegistro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes");
  var calculoF = accesoRegistro.getDataRange();
  var ultimaF = calculoF.getLastRow();
  while (z <= ultimaF) {
    z++;
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes").getRange('A' + z).setValue(now);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes").getRange('C' + z).setValue(nombreCliente);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes").getRange('H' + z).setValue(mensajeConcepto + [suma]);
}
```

Lo que me gustaría, es que la próxima vez que ejecute el script el valor se actualizase.

Comment: Agrega un [mcve] (falta incluir como llamas la función, datos de entrada de ejemplo y l resultado esperado como texto, en lugar de incluirlos como imagen). Asegúrate que el [mcve] esté lo más limpio que puedas (el código declara variables e inmediatamente cambia el valor, por ejemplo `now`, entre otros problemas)

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo tu pregunta, lo que quieres es sobrescribir los datos de fecha y concepto si el cliente es el mismo.

Lo que estas haciendo es irte a la ultima fila a agregar los nuevos datos.

Para sobrescribir si el cliente ya se encuentra en la lista, tienes que obtener el rango (getRange) de los clientes e irlo comparando con la nueva entrada para determinar si se encuentra o no y en qué fila. Sería algo mas o menos así:

```
    function comprobarFacturaPorHoras(nombreCliente, filaCliente, fechaRango) {
     var now = new Date();
     now = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    
    var date = new Date();
      var mt = date.getMonth();
      var months = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"];
      var currentD = months[mt];
      var mensajeConcepto = "Desarrollo horas " + currentD + ': ';
    
     var accesoRegistro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Registro Fin Mes");
      var calculoF = accesoRegistro.getDataRange();
      var ultimaF = calculoF.getLastRow();
      
      var rango = accesoRegistro.getRange(1,2,ultimaF,1).getValues();

      for (let i = 0; i < ultimaF; i++) {
          if (rango[i] == nombreCliente) {
      accesoRegistro.getRange('A' + i).setValue(now);
      accesoRegistro.getRange('C' + i).setValue(nombreCliente);
      accesoRegistro.getRange('H' + i).setValue(mensajeConcepto + [suma]);
           return
           }
        }
         
       
   var nuevaFila = ultimaF+1;
    
      accesoRegistro.getRange('A' + nuevaFila).setValue(now);
      accesoRegistro.getRange('C' + nuevaFila).setValue(nombreCliente);
      accesoRegistro.getRange('H' + nuevaFila).setValue(mensajeConcepto + suma]);
return

        }
```